# When do we need large heap with Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Running ES 1.5.2
JAVA 1.8_45
Windows 2008
4 nodes of 32 Core 128gb RAM 5TB SSDs (Per machine).

My goal is to index about 2.5 billion documents. I am up to 810 million. 30k average per doc.

I currently have ES_HEAP_SIZE=30g

But I have been experience lots of memory pressure and STW pauses. Example: Currently one node is always above 90% heap usage while the rest are coasting anywhere between 30% and 40%. So it seems that 1 node wont GC???

Only 2 things are happening on the cluster bulk indexing (no errors) logged and some scroll searches.

Using doc value where I can. Currently there's no field data cache (except marvel verry small) and filter cache is very minimal about 100MB per node.

The nodes are still trying to recover so i just don't want to stop the cluster fully and reset the RAM to 10GB??

```
How I connect to the cluster in both bulk and scroll search...

// Do this once at application startup and re-use the client instance.
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings
    .settingsBuilder()
    .put("cluster.name", "xxxx")
    .build();

    client = new TransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xxxx", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xxxx", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xxxx", 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("xxxx", 9300));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't send the bulk requests only to one node. The same goes for the search requests.

The bulk request is kept in a memory buffer on the node that receives the request and, obviously, is not a good idea to send any kind of requests to just one node. Round robin the requests either by using a proxy server (if you have one), or by using a [client node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html) and send the requests to that node. The client node knows how to do the round-robin mechanism.

You can, also, look at other options (depending on the clients accessing the cluster) and see if those clients support automatic round-robin/load balancing the requests.

Comment: I'm using the TransportClient and it's configured with the IPs of the 4 nodes. Would it not round robin on it's own? What is a good heap size?

Comment: It's not about heap size. You have nodes with different behaviors, this shouldn't happen. One of your nodes is doing something that others don't. Are you using routing?

Comment: Nope. Btw I updated my main question with how I connect. I also have marvel and kopf running in the browser looking at different statistics. Browsing off one node, but that not the node with the memory pressure issues.

Comment: If you have Marvel, look at different graphs comparing all the four nodes and see what is different in that one with the memory pressure.

Comment: Ok cool. I have stopped all activities on the cluster even disabled all replicas. The cluster currently is only re balancing some unassigned primaries.

Comment: Is it possible that replica shard relocation takes up allot of ram? Right now only primaries are rebalancing. I deleted all replicas and all nodes are about 60% heap usage.

Comment: Humm weird because I haven't bulked or searched anything for passed few ours. But the cluster was trying to recover/rebalance itself and one node was constantly in red. Now just doing primaries and everything is green on the heap side of things.

Comment: Ah also another node I have your kit running and it's reporting 15GB of OLD space being used of the 30GB but I haven't seen that 15GB drop any lower it's just staying there...

Comment: Why was the cluster red? You haven't mentioned anything about red until now.

Comment: This is a long discussion on the issue. The most obvious reason for such an unbalance is overloading one node compared to the others. And, since you mentioned bulk indexing, that fitted the scenario. Other than that, I would look at ES versions (to be the same), configuration (to be correct and be the same), watch for statistics on rejections (bulk, indexing etc), look at hot_threads to see what that particular node is doing and others don't. Any customizations done to the JVM settings?

Comment: Sorry when I meant red is that, the memory for 1 node was constantly red, now memory for all nodes is bellow 75% coasting at 50-60% But I haven't seen any of them drop below that. I'm not doing anything on the cluster at the moment all is disconnected. And I never had bulk index errors. No throttling nothing. I will check it again once the cluster re-balances itself... And using TransportClient so I expect the bulk requests to be round robined.

Comment: Same expectation here.