# When do you need large heap for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let say we are running a moderate cluster with 4 nodes with daily indexes and about 3 billion documents.

Using doc values as much as possible.
Will run mostly scheduled scroll searches and ad hoc tool to build and preview those searches.

Do we really need to set ES_HEAP_SIZE to 30g?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303931/when-do-we-need-large-heap-with-elasticsearch

Comment: Ok so i need to rephrase my question. Why is Elasticsearch taking up all the ram? I have indexed 350 million documents. the bulk request is done, but now each node is at 60% capacity and gc is not collecting anything anymore... I forced GC with your kit and nothing got collected.

Is it the memory mapped files taking the space?

Comment: And btw bulk only takes up a couple of gb and then goes down. This is something different.

Comment: You sound like you blame me for the memory usage :-P. Use `GET /_nodes/stats/indices` to look at things like `filter_cache`, `fielddata`, `segments`, `query_cache` to see what amount of memory is being used. That should count as heap.

Comment: No, no! Just wondering what the issue is. Like I said all that is minimal. Unless Elastic HQ is lying, field data is about 5mb per node and filter cache about 30mb per node. So where would the other 15GB be coming from? So each node now is taking 15GB and not collecting. I asked here also with more details: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/large-heap-usage-with-each-node/969

Comment: Have you checked that command? What is `segments` showing?

Comment: "segments": {
               "count": 18591,
               "memory_in_bytes": 6164548110,
               "index_writer_memory_in_bytes": 0,
               "index_writer_max_memory_in_bytes": 4691267670,
               "version_map_memory_in_bytes": 0,
               "fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes": 0
            }

That's for 1 node it's about the same for the rest.

Comment: So, half your heap goes to segments :-). But you have quite a lot of them. Have you considered [optimizing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/optimize.html) the indices? This should help the memory usage.

Comment: I thought ES would do that on it's own...

Comment: It does, but under certain conditions. A forced optimize (see the link in my previous comment) will do it no matter what. One note though: do this if you don't have much activity on the cluster, because it is resource intensive.

Comment: The one going back to my original post?

Comment: It seems we are not going anywhere with this and my advices are not fully considered and taken with a mocking attitude. I wish you good luck with your investigation.

Comment: Sorry if you feel that way. I just saw the "optimize" link. Yeah i'm looking into it. I though you where talking about the other link in your 1st comment.